# How to configure apache and mod_proxy_ajp in order to forward ssl client certificate

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl-certificate, mod-proxy-ajp

I've developed a java application that need a ssl client certificate and in the staging environment with apache 2.2 and mod_jk it is working fine. In production the configuration is not using mod_jk but mod_proxy_ajp. I'm looking for an apache configuration example that configure ssl and mod_proxy_ajp for sending the ssl client certificate to the java application server (which listens with the ajp protocol).
Thanks a lot

Comment: You should keep staging and production the same. Otherwise you will get more of these problems.

Comment: I can't get the mod_jk configuration working. Can you help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58240796/pass-username-and-client-certificate-from-apache-to-tomcat-using-mod-jk

Answer (score 1):

Using *mod_proxy_ajp*, you will need to set the `RequestHeader` directive to pass through the SSL parameters. Just refer to the Apache [docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_headers.html) for examples on setting the directive either in a `<Location>` or `<VirtualHost>` section.

Answer (score 0):

I setup an apache web server and I found that mod_ajp forwards the client certificate without explicit configuration.
my apache configurations is
SSLEngine on
SSLOptions +StdEnvVars +ExportCertData
ProxyRequests Off
SSLVerifyClient optional_no_ca

        Allow from All

ProxyPass /sportellosociale ajp://localhost:8009/sportellosociale 
ProxyPassReverse /sportellosociale ajp://localhost:8009/sportellosociale*

I omitted the SSLCertificate directives

Answer (score 0):

Mine is configured like so (although this configuration breaks any additional mod_rewrite rules that I create... and i dont know why):

```
<Location />
    ProxyPass ajp://localhost:8009/
    ProxyPassReverse ajp://localhost:8009/
</Location>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} 
Redirect permanent / https://mysite.com/myapp?user=
```